Download Audio Dataset from WikiMedia Commons
I am working on a project that requires an audio dataset from this page
text It shows the audio files but I am unable to figure out how to download the whole dataset at once.
Can anyone help me out?
If I click on each file it shows a download option for the file but can't find a way to download the whole dataset at once

Lingua Libre offers downloads directly on their website: https://lingualibre.org/wiki/Help:Download_datasets

You could use the api, for example use this link:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Lingua_Libre_pronunciation-ory&cmtype=file&cmlimit=500&format=json
See here for documentation:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers
Then process that json, for example with a php scrip of the following form:
<?php

$all_file_names = [];

$base_url = 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Lingua_Libre_pronunciation-ory&cmtype=file&cmlimit=500&format=json';

$cmcontinue = '';
$filepages = []

do {
    $result = file_get_contents( $base_url . '&cmcontinue=' . $cmcontinue );
    $result = json_decode( $result, true );
    $filepages = array_merge( $filepages, $result['query']['categorymembers']);
    $cmcontinue = !empty( $result['continue'] ) ? $result['continue']['cmcontinue'] : false;
} while ( $cmcontinue );

foreach ( $filepages as $filepage ) {
    $url = 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Redirect/file/' . urlencode( $filepage['title'] );
    echo "Downloading file {$filepage['title']}...\n";
    file_put_contents( $filepage['title'], fopen( $url, 'r' ) );
}

Note: This is example code, proper code would do some more checks, e.g. check if all keys in output do exist, sanitize filename.
